# for loop of subjobs using qsub R

Tags: r, qsub

I am trying to run subjobs (one for each chromosome) using `R --vanilla`. Since each chromosome is independent I want them to run parallel in the system. I have written the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
for K in {20..21};
do 
qsub -V -cwd -b y -q short.q  R --vanilla --args arg1$K arg2$K arg3$K < RareMETALS.R > loggroup$K.txt; done
```

But somehow R opens interactively and not in command line as suppose... when trying the script itself

```
R --vanilla --args arg1 arg2 arg3 < RareMETALS.R > loggroup.txt; done
```

It runs perfectly calling the script.

Can someboby guide me, or point out which might be the problem.

Comment: You need to run `Rscript` instead of `R`

Comment: Is this Sun Grid Engine's qsub? Perhaps you should write a command file, pass the args to R via that, and ditch the `-b y` option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My take on this would be to use `echo` instead of `--args` option to pass parameters to the script. I find separating the script and the Grid Engine code to be more straightforward:

```
for K in {20..21};
do 
    echo "Rscript RareMETALS.R arg1$K arg2$K arg3$K > loggroup$K.txt" | qsub -V -cwd -q short.q
done
```

As others have commented use `Rscript`.

Code seems cleaner to me, but there may be some limitations to using `echo` as opposed to `--args` I am unaware of.

Comment: 1. Why `echo` instead of `--args`? 2. Instead of `echo … | cmd` you can use `cmd <<< …` (or `<<< … cmd`, if you prefer that order).

Comment: 1. Inertia. That is what I learned and I have not needed anything else yet. But `--args` is always an option. 2. Again, inertia. Here strings (http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17837.html) are quite cool, albeit more advanced than `echo`, IMO.